# How to avoid content clipped by ScrollView scrollbar?

Tags: android

I have a plain vanilla layout:

```
<ScrollView>
    <TableLayout>
        <TableRow>
            ...
```

but the content gets clipped by the ScrollViews scrollbar.

This link illustrates the issue:
http://books.google.com/books?id=7tH3A0UrWEEC&lpg=PA54&ots=zztpvVWPXT&dq=android%20%22clipped%20by%20the%20scrollbar%22&pg=PA54#v=onepage&q&f=false

**How to avoid content clipped by ScrollView scrollbar ?**

Edit:
Adding android:layout_marginRight="5dip" on ScrollView leaves ugly gap on righthand side of emulator screen. See below.

Any other tips ?

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/96193a3b6e.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/96193a3b6e.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you just have to add a margin of 5 or 10px on the right, in your `TableLayout`!

Comment: Adding android:layout_marginRight="5dip" on ScrollView leaves ugly gap on righthand side of emulator screen. See above.

Any other tips ?

Comment: Oh sorry, that's not on the scrollview that you need to apply this, but on the tablelayout.Otherwise, as you showed it, you just resize the scrollview

Answer (score 5):

On the ScrollView, use android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset". This should push the content over by the width of the scrollbar, but leave the scrollbar itself against the edge of the screen.

Comment: Exactly what the doctor ordered!